# How can I prevent "Eject <device>" appearing after installing a WinUSB-based device?

Tags: installation, usb, inf, winusb

### Summary

I'm developing an installer for an application that involves installing a USB device based on WinUSB. Everything works except for an annoying issue in which the USB device shows up in the notification pane after installation with the option to safely remove it:

[image]

I don't want this option to appear but I'm not sure how to go about preventing it. I believe it should be possible by adding the right directives to the INF file for the device, but Microsoft have done a fantastic job making the INF file format stupidly overcomplicated and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what to do [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-files).

### What I've Tried

The Microsoft docs really aren't helpful enough, but I managed to find an old document called [Designing Hardware For Surprise Removal Under Windows XP](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwixs6_ck-bXAhWIK8AKHa7zD1kQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F1%2F6%2F1%2F161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c%2Fdesigning%2520hardware%2520for%2520surprise%2520removal_v8.doc&usg=AOvVaw2CwaemVvFIyr6lzWAWrpgj) that seemed promising:

[image]

Based on this I tried adding the following content to my INF file:

```inf
[USB_Install.HW]
...
AddReg=Dev_AddReg_HW_Removal_Policy

[Dev_AddReg_HW_Removal_Policy]
HKR,,"RemovalPolicy",0x00010001,2
```

After installing this driver, I went to device manager and was able to confirm that the "Removal policy" property was set to `00000002` (it was `00000003` before). However, the device still showed up with an "Eject" option.

My next attempt was with "Safe removal required", which is currently set to `<true>`. I had a stab at including the directive for this in my INF file:

```inf
[USB_Install.HW]
...
AddReg=Dev_AddReg_HW_Removal_Policy
AddReg=Dev_AddReg_HW_Safe_Removal_Required

[Dev_AddReg_HW_Removal_Policy]
HKR,,"RemovalPolicy",0x00010001,2

[Dev_AddReg_HW_Safe_Removal_Required]
HKR,,"SafeRemovalRequired",0x00010001,0
```

I used `infverif` to confirm my INF file was valid, but after installing this version of the driver the "Safe removal required" property is still set to `<true>` and the device still features an eject option.

Is anyone familiar enough with the convoluted (and quite frankly retarded) INF format to suggest what I need to change to make the "Eject" option disappear?

Comment: I think having two `AddReg=` directives is suspicious.  Try putting the HKR lines in one section and just having one `AddReg=` line to refer to that section.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I gave it a shot, it didn't seem to make a difference.